# Performance benefits of upgrading Jetty 7.x to 8.x

Tags: java, jetty

Bugs/features aside are there any obvious performance benefits to upgrade from Jetty 7 to 8. I am trying to look for empirical performance data on Jetty 7 to 8 to validate an upgrade. Wondering if such a comparison exists.

Comment: Off topic. Belongs on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 3):

There should be no performance difference between Jetty 7 and Jetty 8.

They are the same codebase, with the only differences being what version of the servlet-api they support.  Jetty 7 and Jetty 8 are developed in parallel, with changes going into Jetty 7 and then merged up to Jetty 8.

- Jetty 7 - Servlet API 2.5
- Jetty 8 - Servlet API 3.0

Now, Jetty 9 (Currently in late milestone releases), on the other hand, has had a complete overhaul of the I/O layer and is proving to be more performant than Jetty 7 and Jetty 8.

Comment: Ah interesting, any comparison links between Jetty 9 and 8 or Jetty 9 and 7?